# Fixed Entity to Camera not showing in VR Mode

Tags: aframe, webvr

I was wondering if there is a problem with my code or is there some work around I need to do this is what I have:

```
<a-scene>
    <a-sky id="preview_image" src="/assets/img/example.jpg" 
        refresh-event="trigger_event: new_frame_loaded"></a-sky>
    <a-entity camera look-controls>
        <a-circle
            color= "red"
            position= "38 18 -20">
        </a-circle>
    </a-entity>
</a-scene>
```

It works fine in preview mode. I think I might be running A-frame version: 0.9.0

Comment: maybe you could share screenshot what is working fine and what is not working

Answer (score 1):

I assume the problem seems like you don't see your red circle `<a-circle>`. It is because the circle is out of your boundary.

just change it to

```
<a-circle color= "red" position= "0 0 -1"></a-circle> 
<!-- -1 so it will in front of the <a-sky> -->
```

Comment: Ah you're right, it was out of bounds and didn't appear in the VR mode. Which is kind of odd since it shown up as ok in the preview

Comment: Glad to solve your problem. Please close your question by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer that helped you most